# write image to blobstore from url

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

This question is simlar to [How to upload image from url to Blobstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665966/how-to-upload-image-from-url-to-blobstore), but now the `google.appengine.api.files` is deprecated.

What I have is a web form where the user insert a url and the image should be uploaded to the blobstore. Then on server side I fetch the url to get the image data and I create a `google.appengine.api.files`.

Is it possibile to do it without `google.appengine.api.files`? I would like to keep it simple as in the case when the user submit an image and the server uses `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler`

**Maybe can I do something on the client side, to fetch the image on the client and then to use the same approach with `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler`?**

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use urlfetch (or urllib2) to fetch the image(on server side, based on the url passed in).

Then you can use [gcs client](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/) to upload the image to the blobstore.

Here's a snippet from the [demo](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/python/demo/main.py):

```
def create_file(self, filename):
    """Create a file.
    The retry_params specified in the open call will override the default
    retry params for this particular file handle.

    Args:
      filename: filename.
    """
    self.response.write('Creating file %s\n' % filename)

    write_retry_params = gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                'w',
                content_type='text/plain',
                options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                         'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
                retry_params=write_retry_params)
    gcs_file.write('abcde\n')
    gcs_file.write('f'*1024*1024 + '\n')
    gcs_file.close()
    self.tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)
```

Comment: thank you, but as I said I would like to keep it simple, so no gcs, but only blobstore. Actually I am confused about the difference.

Comment: I agree, it is confusing that GAE started using different approaches. You can create a blob_key from the gcs file by calling create_gs_key https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_gs_key

Comment: So write the file to gcs, then call blobstore.create_gs_key (which creates the blob key, which you *should* be able to serve the image from). I'm not sure where the delete functionality ties in.